# Rails cannot load such file -- sassc-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried to run `rails server` but got the following error:

```
<internal:/Users/familyrutscher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require': cannot load such file -- dartsass-sprockets (LoadError)
```

and

```
<internal:/Users/familyrutscher/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require': cannot load such file -- sassc-rails (LoadError)
```

How do I fix these errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using bootstrap gem, and then getting this error you can resolve errosr by

1. Add to `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`

> @import "bootstrap";

2. Add to `app/assets/javascript/application.js` or to `app/javascript/application.js`

```js
//= require jquery3
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

3. if you're getting this error again then add this gem

> gem "sassc-rails"

Now, your error will be resolved.

Thanks!